# Can I recover lost commits in a SVN repository using a local tracking git-svn branch?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

A SVN repo I use git-svn to track was recently corrupted and a backup was recovered. However, a week's worth of commits were lost in the recovery. Is it possible to recover those lost commits using `git-svn dcommit` on my local git repo? Is it sufficient to run `git-svn dcommit` with the SHA1 of the last recovered commit in SVN? eg.

```
> svn info http://tracked-svn/trunk | sed -n "s/Revision: //p"
252
> git log --grep="git-svn-id:.*@252" --format=oneline | cut -f1 -d" "
55bb5c9cbb5fe11a90ec2e9e1e0c7c502908cf9a
> git svn dcommit 55bb5c9cbb5fe11a90ec2e9e1e0c7c502908cf9a
```

Or will the `git-svn-id` need to be stripped from the intended commits?

I tried this using `--dry-run` but couldn't tell whether it would try to submit all commits:

```
> git svn dcommit --verbose --dry-run 55bb5c9cbb5fe11a90ec2e9e1e0c7c502908cf9a
Committing to http://tracked-svn/trunk ...
dcommitted on a detached HEAD because you gave a revision argument.
The rewritten commit is: 55bb5c9cbb5fe11a90ec2e9e1e0c7c502908cf9a
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I achieved what I wanted:

1. Re-cloned `http://tracked-svn/trunk` in a fresh git-svn repo.
2. Added my old git-svn repo as a remote to the fresh repo. (eg. `git remote add -f up-to-date /path/to/repo`)
3. `git merge remotes/up-to-date/master`
4. `git svn dcommit`

Rebasing on my old repo gives no errors, and dcommit works as expected.

This might not be the best way to recover commits, but it got me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but [that thread](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg02226.html) may explain a bit the error message:

> '`git svn dcommit`' takes an optional revision argument, but the meaning of it was rather scary.
>   It completely ignored the current state of the `HEAD`, only looking at the revisions between SVN and `$rev`.
>   If HEAD was attached to $branch, the branch lost all commits $rev..$branch in the process.
>
> Considering that '`git svn dcommit HEAD^`' has the intuitive meaning "`dcommit` all changes on my branch except the last one", we change the meaning of the revision argument.
>   git-svn temporarily checks out `$rev` for its work, meaning that:
>
> - if a branch is specified, that branch (*not* the `HEAD`) is rebased as part of the `dcommit`,
> - if some other revision is specified, as in the example, all work happens on a detached HEAD and no branch is affected.

I am not sure if that patch has been integrated in version Git, but if you test your dcommit, make sure to `git branch -b` after the `dcommit`, to reference the current HEAD with a branch.
Will it work on the SVN side? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that shed some light on the [`detached_head` situation](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/detached-head.html).

I've been dealing with more or less the same issue here and this is what I ended up doing:

- First, always make sure you're on a valid branch `git branch`
- If you see `(no branch)` (w/asterisk indicating "current branch"), that means you have a detached head
- Checkout the detached head `git co -b [BRANCH NAME] --track`.  Using the `--track` option, *I THINK* makes it track the `git-svn` HEAD and therefore reattachs this new branch to a HEAD.
- Continue with `git svn rebase/dcommit` commands per usual.

This is probably bad, but this also seemed to help - I deleted the `master` branch and then after doing a `git svn rebase`, it seems to add back in the `master` branch automatically.

Also, I viewed the logs of a file and it seems that once I did a `git svn dcommit`, all the git checkins were intact from when my branch started going crazy and I was trying to do whatever I could to get it set back correctly.

I'm not 100% sure this is completely correct, but I this seemed to work for me.