# mysterious vanishing branches in git

Tags: git, version-control, backup, branch, github

Here are some git actions I performed. As you can see, I made a new branch, modified my files, and then committed the changes. After changing back to another branch, hoping to merge, the branch I was just working on disappeared.

Does anyone know how I can recover the files from fixed_merge_branch? I'm freaking out!

```
1.9.2@whisperme$ git branch fixed_merge_conflict
1.9.2@whisperme$ git checkout fixed_merge_conflict
M   ArtworkViewController.h
M   ArtworkViewController.m
M   ArtworkViewController.xib
M   Classes/DFRAppDelegate.h
M   Classes/DFRAppDelegate.m
M   Classes/WorkGalleryViewController.m
M   Classes/WorkGalleryViewController.xib
M   DFR.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
M   DFRViewController.xib
M   Data.h
M   Data.m
M   MainWindow.xib
M   cn.lproj/Localizable.strings
M   en.lproj/Localizable.strings
A   fr.lproj/Localizable.strings
Switched to branch 'fixed_merge_conflict'
1.9.2@whisperme$ git add .
1.9.2@whisperme$ cd Classes/
1.9.2@whisperme$ git add .
1.9.2@whisperme$ cd ..
1.9.2@whisperme$ git add -u
1.9.2@whisperme$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   ArtworkViewController.h
#   modified:   ArtworkViewController.m
#   modified:   ArtworkViewController.xib
#   modified:   Classes/DFRAppDelegate.h
#   modified:   Classes/DFRAppDelegate.m
#   modified:   Classes/WorkGalleryViewController.m
#   modified:   DFR.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
#   modified:   Data.h
#   modified:   Data.m
#   modified:   MainWindow.xib
#   modified:   cn.lproj/Localizable.strings
#   modified:   en.lproj/Localizable.strings
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   fr.lproj/
1.9.2@whisperme$ git commit -m "re-did changes lost by merge screw up"
[detached HEAD 858491f] re-did changes lost by merge screw up
 12 files changed, 110 insertions(+), 50 deletions(-)
1.9.2@whisperme$ git checkout develop
Previous HEAD position was 858491f... re-did changes lost by merge screw up
Switched to branch 'develop'
1.9.2@whisperme$ git branch
  artwork_model
  artwork_model_localisation
  artwork_screen
* develop
  logger
  master
  start_artwork_model
1.9.2@whisperme$ git merge fixed_merge_conflict
fatal: 'fixed_merge_conflict' does not point to a commit
1.9.2@whisperme$ git checkout fixed_merge_conflict
error: pathspec 'fixed_merge_conflict' did not match any file(s) known to git.
1.9.2@whisperme$ git checkout fixed_merge_conflict
error: pathspec 'fixed_merge_conflict' did not match any file(s) known to git.
1.9.2@whisperme$ git branch
  artwork_model
  artwork_model_localisation
  artwork_screen
* develop
  logger
  master
  start_artwork_model
1.9.2@whisperme$ git checkout
1.9.2@whisperme$ git branch
  artwork_model
  artwork_model_localisation
  artwork_screen
* develop
  logger
  master
  start_artwork_model
1.9.2@whisperme$ pwd
/Users/tristan/Documents/DFR
1.9.2@whisperme$
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well I don't exactly see why the branch 'disappeared' but don't worry, your files didn't.

You can find them by many means:

- You can use the message printed by the `git checkout` when you left your anonymous branch: "Previous HEAD position was 858491f".
- You can use `git reflog` and find the commit of your files.

Then you can run this to recreate the branch:

```
git checkout 858491f -b fixed_merge_conflict
```

and then you can do your merge:

```
git checkout develop
git merge fixed_merge_conflict
```

Or you can do the merge in one step if you don't care about the branch:

```
git merge 858491f
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, you're getting a [`detach head` situation](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/detached-head.html).  I'm not entirely sure how that is caused in a regular git repo, but i've encountered it using `git svn` ([and came up with my own solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710073/can-i-recover-lost-commits-in-a-svn-repository-using-a-local-tracking-git-svn-bra)).  It might be that the aren't `--track`ing the upstream repo when you create a new branch.  Usually when you get a `detached head`, when you do a `git branch`, you will see `(asterisk) (no branch)` (don't know how to do a literal asterisk with markdown)

Comment: links are rotten

Answer (score 0):

I've seen git branches seem to "disappear", then I realized I was in the wrong directory.  git branch will give different results in different directories.