# git doesn't see branches after reinstallation osx

Tags: git, macos, git-branch

I'm very new to git. After complete osx reinstall I've noticed that I can't switch to other branches I've created before… There is only master:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ git branch -a
  * master
  remotes/origin/master
```

On github I see all my 4 brunches… I want to recover them…

Could anyone explain me how can make available my other branches?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` print?

Comment: Thanx for reply. Updated the post

Comment: Just checkout the branches again. `git fetch` then `git checkout branch_name`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743795/mysterious-vanishing-branches-in-git

Comment: this didn't help because `git reflog` returns only this:  `e3c2fee HEAD@{11}: pull --ff --no-rebase --quiet origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
220d300 HEAD@{12}: pull --ff --no-rebase --quiet origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
144e870 HEAD@{13}: pull --ff --no-rebase --quiet origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
02e5c4a HEAD@{14}: reset: moving to origin/master`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer myself:

```
$ git fetch origin

# check all(remote branches):
$ git branch -v -a

#check out the branch(get local working copy):
$ git checkout -b test origin/test
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are new to Github , i'd strongly suggest you to use github Desktop application to avoid complexities.You can easily manage your branches here. Command-line is always there to backup you up when you get used to the environment,concepts and stuff.

https://desktop.github.com

Comment: Good advice for beginners, however, merely switching to GitHub's Desktop application would most likely not create the local branches.